# Replace an existing url in given text with a new url using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace an existing url in given text with a new url using regex. I don't seem to get any matches for the regex pattern I'm using:

```
string regex = "<a href=\"http://domain/page.asp?id=(\\d+)&amp;oid=(\\d+)&amp;type=(\\w+)\">";
```

Can someone please assist me write a correct pattern to find urls that look like:

```
"<A href=\"http://domain/page.asp?id=38957&amp;oid=2497&amp;type=JPG\">"
```

Below is my test code which cannot find any matches for the pattern I'm using:

```
string result = string.Empty;

string sampleText = "<A href=\"http://domain/page.asp?id=38957&amp;oid=2497&amp;type=JPG\"><U>Click here for Terms &amp; Conditions...</U></A>";

string regex = "<a href=\"http://domain/page.asp?id=(\\d+)&amp;oid=(\\d+)&amp;type=(\\w+)\">";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

result= regEx.Replace(text, "<a href=\"/newPage/Index/$1&opid=$2)\">");
```

Comment: "can't get it working" is not very descriptive. What isn't working? Errors? Exceptions? Please post what you _expect_ to happen vs what _is_ happening.

Comment: Very difficult to choose an exact duplicate on the 'related' list. However, don't use Regex, use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: What @Steve said, in conjunction with the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to parse the URLs once you get them using the HAP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Regex replace url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945238/c-sharp-regex-replace-url)

Comment: Just to point you in the right direction if you still want to go down the Regex route: Look into escape characters. e.g. ? makes the previous character optional. so ...page.asp?id matches ...page.asid or page.aspid but NOT page.asp?id

Comment: You should not use regex for that. Use HtmlAgilityPack. Not only you will avoid some evil regex injection, but you will also support any kind of `<a>` tag construction (with multiline, forgotten double quotes, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine except that `.` and `?` are special characters in regular expressions, so they need to be escaped to be treated as literals.  So your expression:

```
string regex = "<a href=\"http://domain/page.asp?id=(\\d+)&amp;oid=(\\d+)&amp;type=(\\w+)\">";
```

Needs to be:

```
string regex = "<a href=\"http://domain/page\\.asp\\?id=(\\d+)&amp;oid=(\\d+)&amp;type=(\\w+)\">";
```

Note the backslashes in front of the `.` and `?`.